# Force user to a single site when visiting over a specific domain via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I try to force a user which is coming via a specific domain `example-page.com` to always get redirected to `/countdown`

My approach was the the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example-page\.com [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example-page\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/countdown
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example-page.com/countdown [L,R=301]
```

But for some reason I always get a "Too many redirects error".
I get redirected to the `https://www.example-page.com/countdown` but somehow the RewriteCond is triggered again but it should not because of the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/countdown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this rule:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example-page\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/countdown [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example-page.com/countdown [L,R=301]
```

Make sure to test if after clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, with your shown samples. Please keep these Rules at top of your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example-page\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/countdown
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example-page.com/countdown [L,R=301]
```

Also why you are getting error because you have space between `NC` and `OR`(`NC, OR`) which is causing that 500 internal error.